# MySQL / Query Execution With Debugger?

Tags: mysql, linux, system, admin, administration

Hey there Stack Overflow,

I had a pretty radical idea last night... but I couldn't figure out how to even start to do this. I learned that I can reset the set max_connection limit in MySQL with gdb... I was wondering if there is a way to execute MySQL queries with gdb as well. This would have implications like being able to reset a lost root password without a server reboot.

So is there a way to use gdb or some other tool to influence MySQL to execute queries without a client connection?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you'd have to replicate the entire login sequence so you can establish the appropriate credentials to do password changes, which is probably a bit much to expect of gd.

Comment: Do you happen to know which part of the source code does this? I might be able to script it out with gdb -p $(cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid) -ex 'GDB COMMANDS HERE' -batch